# GridBagLayout middle and bottom buttons

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I am setting a layout for some buttons. I am trying to have 2 buttons in the middle, and one at the end. I have two in the middle, but the one at the end is off to the side. How can I set the "back" button to be below the other buttons. (I have researched this).

```
public class Options extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Back");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("Textures");
    JButton b5 = new JButton("Settings");

public Options()
{
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.ipadx = 5;
    add(b5, c);
    c.ipadx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    add(b4, c);
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    add(b1, c);
 }
}
```

[image: My layout error]

EDIT:
I have updated my code above. The offset error has been fixed, but b5 is on top instead of centered (b4 is centerd, b1 is on the bottom).

Comment: Have you tried adding a `GridBagConstraints` associated with the `layout` object as well, and setting the `gridx` property of both `GridBagConstraint` objects to the same index?

Comment: Settings constrains for layout does nothing. I set gridx = 0 and gridy = 1. The problem is that layout is at the top of the screen, and b1 is at the bottom.

Comment: Create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) if we're to fully understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Hope the second example in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11428289/1057230), might be able to help you out (though you can use JPanel instead of JLabel as used in that example.)

Comment: @Coupon22 Can you be precise as to where you want the buttons to be?  What do you mean by `b5 is on top instead of centered`?  Maybe a picture of the expected result might help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be close enough to the layout I think you are trying to get:

```
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel layout = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    layout.add(new JButton("Settings"));
    layout.add(new JButton("Textures"));

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    add(layout, c);

    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weighty = 0.1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    add(new JButton("Back"), c);
```

Comment: I tried to do it with just 1 layout, but oh well. 2 works.            This is the layout I want, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set `c.gridx` to be `0`:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
```

Comment: The layout is at the top of the screen, and b1 is at the bottom.

Comment: You are adding your `layout` `JPanel` and the `back` button using 2 different layouts. Can you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?