# How do you add a button on top of a picture in jpanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

```
import java.awt.*;   
import javax.swing.*;  

public class Game
{  

  MyDrawPanel draw;  

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
    new Game().go();   
  }  

  public void go()
  { 
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Revenge");  
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();  
    draw=new MyDrawPanel();         
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,draw);  
    frame.setSize(750,360);  
    frame.setVisible(true);    
  }  
  public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel
  {  
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {              
      Image image=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\zep\\Desktop\\title.png").getImage();  
      g.drawImage(image,0,0,this);
    }  
  }  
}
```

So basically I need help trying to add a button. I am extremely new to java and I need to do this for my CPT in my class. Please help you will be my hero :3

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`, you'll end up with nasty repaint artifacts if you don't.  Also, you shouldn't be trying to load an image within the `paintComponent` method, paint methods should return fast and may be called multiple times within quick succession...

Comment: Oh dear...should we even try to indicate on bad thing he made in his code..

Comment: @brano88 Like not adhering to the requirements of [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?  Or the fact that a `JLabel` would do the same thing?  Or he should be overriding `getPreferredSize` and using `Window#pack` instead of `setSize`?

Comment: At least he uses layouts. :)

Comment: @brano88 And doesn't mix heavy and light weight components and didn't try using a `J/Applet` :P

Comment: Hopefully this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11428289/1057230) might be of some help...

Answer (score 4):

Well...just create new button and add it on your drawPanel. Like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Text goes here");
drawPanel.add(button);
```

Default layout for drawPanel is `FlowLayout` so your button should be centered on top of that panel.
Or, if you want your button above your picture, add it on `panel`:

```
panel.add(button);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Text goes here");
drawPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Where do i put it. Thanks for the help :)