# Setting radio buttons to a background

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jradiobutton

I was trying to set Radio Button to a background in order to allow the user to select.

Here is the code ..

```
public class FirstWindow extends JFrame {

    private JTextField search;
    private JRadioButton author,title,both;
    private ButtonGroup grp;

    public FirstWindow() {
       super("My App");
       setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel backGround = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kareem Abdo\\Desktop\\3.Jpg"));
    backGround.setLayout(null);
    add(backGround);

    search = new JTextField("Search...");
    search.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,16));
    search.setSize(150, 30);
    search.setLocation(20, 20);
    backGround.add(search);

    author = new JRadioButton("Author",true);
    author.setLocation(20, 25);
    backGround.add(author);

    title = new JRadioButton("Title",false);
    title.setLocation(25, 25);
    backGround.add(title);

    both = new JRadioButton("Both",false);
    both.setLocation(250, 250);
    backGround.add(both);

    grp = new ButtonGroup();
    grp.add(author);
    grp.add(title);
    grp.add(both);
```

But the radio buttons doesn't appear on the screen!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space. 3) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.

Comment: You are specifying only `location`, but no size for `JRadioButton`. You need to specify that too, but since its a completely wrong approach you taking, I won't say a word after this :-)

Comment: Please have a look at this related [example (2nd code)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11428289/1057230)

Answer (score 3):

- `JLabel (JLabel backGround = new JLabel`) haven't implemented any `LayoutManager`, [then you have to set the proper one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel), otherwise any `JComponent` added to `JLabel` isn't visible
- maybe better could be start with [`Image (BufferedImage)` painted in `paintComponent` to the `JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) (pre_implemented `FlowLayout` in API)

Comment: i had set the layout of backGround to null in order to be able to sort the components as I want, I don't want the layout manager to sort them

Comment: *"I don't want the layout manager to sort them"*  Then expect all the types of problems currently being seen, & stop bothering us.  If you had the smarts to layout the components, you could put that logic in a custom layout manager (tip: this question indicates you don't).