# which layout manager would be appropriate to my design?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am a beginner to Java. I would like some help in Swings to position my components.

I am not able to decide as which layout manager should I use to position my components in the following order

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
|      Username  Text Field         |
|      Password  Password Field     |
|                                   |
|           Submit button           |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

The following is my code

```
    package ssst;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

class Test implements ActionListener{



    JButton submit;
    JFrame j;
    JFrame jf;

    public Test()
    {
    j = new JFrame("PLAIN");
    j.setBounds(500,150,300,400);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    j.add(panel);
    GridBagLayout gb = new GridBagLayout();
    panel.setLayout(gb);


    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();



    JLabel label = new JLabel("User Name");
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.ipadx=5;
    c.ipady=5;
    c.insets= new Insets(7,7,7,7);

    panel.add(label,c);

    JTextField username = new JTextField(10);

    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=0;

    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.ipadx=5;
    c.insets= new Insets(7,7,7,7);

    panel.add(username,c);

    JLabel password= new JLabel("Password");
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.ipadx=5;
    c.insets= new Insets(7,7,7,7);

    panel.add(password,c);

    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=1;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.insets= new Insets(7,7,7,7);

    panel.add(pass,c);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=6;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.insets= new Insets(7,7,7,7);

    panel.add(submit,c);

    submit.addActionListener(this);
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        j.setVisible(false);
        jf = new JFrame("NEw Window");
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setBounds(500,150,300,400);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(null);
        jf.add(panel2);

        JButton logout = new JButton("LOGOUT");
        logout.setBounds(100, 30, 400, 30);
        panel2.add(logout);
        logout.addActionListener(new Test2());
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(j.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    }


    class Test2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            jf.dispose();
            j.setVisible(true);

        }


    }


public static void main(String args[])
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
            public void run()
            {

                new Test();

            }

    }

            );


}




}
```

Comment: I think this can be easily done with `new GridLayout(3, 2)`, but could also work with `GridBagLayout`, `SpringLayout` or `MigLayout` (the last one is not part of JDK).

Comment: @ZiaKhan, plz don't use null layout, do consider using GridBagLayout for you current requirement, [how to use](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jpanel-basic-tutorial-and-examples)

Comment: Totally Gridbag: http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/

Comment: I'd do this with a combination of three layout managers: BorderLayout as the parent layout; the CENTER position is a JPanel with a SpringLayout (using utility code from the Swing tutorial to easily create a grid) for the input fields with labels, the PAGE_END position is a JPanel with a centered FlowLayout for the button(s).

Comment: Hopefully this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11428289/1057230), be of some help on the topic :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `GridBagLayout` and a `JOptionPane`

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

    private JTextField userName;
    private JPasswordField password;

    public LoginPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        add(new JLabel("Username:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

        userName = new JTextField(10);
        password = new JPasswordField(10);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(userName, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(password, gbc);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return userName.getText();
    }

    public char[] getPassword() {
        return password.getPassword();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                LoginPane loginPane = new LoginPane();
                int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                        null, 
                        loginPane, 
                        "Login", 
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        new Object[]{"Submit"},
                        "Submit");
                if (option == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Happy");
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

You could possibly use `GridLayout` with this concept as well.

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html for more ideas and links to other layout managers

Comment: Can we do this with a Flowlayout ?

Comment: No, FlowLayout is to simplistic for what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

go for GridBagLayout, logic of layout is simple. It works on X and Y co-ordinates.
[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Also you should go through other layout as well, it will help you decide in future designs.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use GridBagLayout, in case if u add new components, Layout manager as to take care to fit the components with in the screen if u (maximized/Restore Down).

Answer (score 1):

It is subjective to say what layout manager is appropriate for a 
design. This design is a no-brainer for the `MigLayout` manager.

For a comparison, I provide a solution with a `MigLayout`.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutLoginEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutLoginEx() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Log in");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("ins 15, wrap 2", "[][grow]"));

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("User name:");
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Password:");
        JPasswordField field2 = new JPasswordField(10);  

        JButton btn = new JButton("Submit");

        add(lbl1);
        add(field1, "growx");
        add(lbl2);
        add(field2, "growx");
        add(btn, "span 2, center, gaptop 20");

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutLoginEx ex = new MigLayoutLoginEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The layout is achieved with six lines of layout code.

[image: Login]