# JButton background image text

Tags: java, swing

I placed an image on a JButton using the `btn.setIcon` method.The problem is that the text is pushed right by the image and I can see the background button color and only the first letter of the text even thogh their horizontal alignement are both placed on center(I tried all variations).

NOTE:What I need is a full background image with the text OVER the image.Not just an icon.

**How can I make that happen?**

If you post your code, as a working example, we will be able to give more help. –  user2891133

There it is:

```
public void placeResizedImage(JBUtton btn){
            URL buttonImage=this.getClass().getResource("/source/woodButton.png");
            BufferedImage bg=null;
            try {
                bg = ImageIO.read(buttonImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Background image does not exist!");
                return null;
            }
            Image imageBuff=bg.getScaledInstance((int)btn.getSize().getWidth(),(int) btn.getSize().getHeight(),
            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageBuff));
        }
```

Comment: If you post your code, as a working example, we will be able to give more help.

Comment: I posted the resizing and the setting if the button is needed ill post that too

Comment: As far as I know, the JButton does not provide these features. I guess you have to use a JLabel. I might be wrong, 'though.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427743/adding-image-to-jbutton-with-foreground-label) mentions the code you need.

Comment: Partially it does but i need the text over the image...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JButton button = new JButton( "Centered" );
button.setIcon( new ImageIcon("mong.jpg") );
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
```

Comment: Oooh it must be AFTER the .setIcon method.Thank u and sorry.

Comment: @GeorgiDzhondzhov, the order doesn't matter. You are just setting properties of the button.