# How to add image to JFrame as background and still add other components to it?

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe

i want to add an Image as a background to a JFrame but not like

```
    this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new IamgeIcon("path of image file"));
```

When i use the above code line i can not see my other components added to the same JFrame.
I want to set an image as a background as we see in the html pages where body has a background image and we see other components like buttons and textboxes over it. Can anyone please show me how to do that? And I want to attach 2 more panels to same JFrame.Please attach the image of your code output.

Comment: looks like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645452/background-image-in-a-jframe?rq=1

Comment: @WillHartung yes... thanx! I did not find that in searches!

Comment: @WillHartung, but if i make such a panel with an image painted over it, and add it to JFrame using border layout,it will take it's place at either north or south or center or east or west. It will not act as a whole background.... isn't it? I have other 2 panels to add to same JFrame...

Comment: A component added to the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout` will fill the entire space so long as not components are added at the other positions.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168119/gradient-background-in-a-jframe/21171391#21171391) for an MCVE much like you are trying to achieve (with nice screen-shots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **JLayeredPane**

**JLayeredPane** adds depth to a JFC/Swing container, allowing components to overlap each other when needed.

link [how to use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

and check this [example](http://madushankaperera.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/how-to-add-background-image-to-a-jframe/)

Comment: I think a `JLayeredPane` is not really the way to go here, and would need to see an MCVE before I'd be convinced otherwise.  As to the links, they should best have descriptive text, like the 2nd, as opposed to text of `link`..

Comment: This [`AnimationTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) use the default layout for components; click few times and then resize to see the effect.